# Ignoring non required field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my code to ignore a specific field that doesn't require text at all, but if it has anything other than numeric values in it, it will give me an error. Instead, it gives me the errors when Nothing is entered.
The code I have in question is a regex function for checking numeric value, my validation function calls to the numeric regex function, and
if

```
input.classList.contains "numeric".
```

If the regex is not validated, it will give an error.

Comment: Your code , please

Comment: I added my code @YarinLevi

Comment: What does ignore mean? Also, could include html code as well?

Comment: @James by ignore I mean, the text field in question should pass through form validation, even if the text field is empty. But if I type something such as a letter or special character, I get the error I am looking for.

Comment: @James You're referring to my Javascript code? I cannot touch the HTML file, as that is from a template for my project. What do you mean by some input?

Comment: @GMarshall, for some input like phone number, there is a default input type for it. Your code is too messy and has a lot of if conditions

Comment: @James That kind of what they want it to look like. The project requirements are kind of specific in a lot of areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `/^([0-9])+$/` in `checkNumeric()` expects at least one digit because of the `+`. Try `/^([0-9])*$/`. This accepts empty string as well, because `*` matches 0 til infinity digits.

EDIT: I created a [program showing the regex in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBATiDmIA8IF4IHoB6AKA2gBgFoBOAXQEoAqAEjQChbRJEBDAWwAdQBnFCHAIgAsAJn4AaCP3GSAFiGDAA9vxL0WHbgDoAZoqgBRZgGMZWdZxAoAfBCOKAdl0WhNS2FgAGVqgG9zoAF8AHggAN2ZgAEsAEwB%20CF8YeARNMBAuMDMENgsyAI8yMiA).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't even notice that issue. Can I get one more answer from you? I have a minimum length requirement in there, but even if i meet the requirement, the error message stays. Any idea?

Comment: Sure! Do you mean the length requirements in `checkPhoneNumber()` or the one when checking that a username has at least 8 characters?

Comment: The minimum requirement checker. The checkLength() function, when I call to it in my validate function, it gives the errors when the length is not met, but when I meet the length checker, it keeps the error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your function only returns `true` if `input` and `minLength` are *exactly* equal. But you want that inputs that are longer than `minLength` are also ok, so try replacing `input == minLength` with `input >= minLength`.

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately. @linuskmr

Comment: You also forgot a return or you have to omit the curly braces:
`const checkLength = (input, minLength) => { return input >= minLength };`
or
`const checkLength = (input, minLength) => input >= minLength;`

Comment: Without the return or with just the curly brackets, `undefined` will be returned, leading to `undefined >= 5`, which is always `false`.

Comment: These regex are having the same issue:
Password: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$!%*#?&]).*$/

Date: /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)\d\d*$/

@linuskmr

Comment: @Specialist consider testing for an empty input outside the regex: `input.length == 0 || input.match(...)`.